# Artist Seal Meaning

Tags: meaning, seal

I am trying to identify these artist seal meaning, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.I have tried researching this myself but to no avail

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnuIu.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

The seal says「萅」, which is one of the earlier forms of「春」(*spring*).

---

「春」(Mandarin Pinyin: **chūn**, *spring*) was originally constructed from simultaneously semantic and phonetic「屯」(**tún**, *picture of a sprouting plant*), and various other optionally present semantic components including「木」(*picture of a tree*),「屮・艸」(*grass, plants, vegetation*), and「日」(*sun*), inferring *sun shining on newly sprouting vegetation > spring*. The surviving glyph「春」is from an original combination of「艸・艹」,「日」, and「屯」.

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[粹](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1151
[合集29715](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=29715&jgwfl=)</kbd>

> In the above character,「艸」is split into two「屮」, which surround「日」, all on the left hand side.「屯」is the portion found on the right.
>
> - The combination of「艸」and「日」here survives as a component in a few characters, e.g. the left hand side of「朝」.

Later on, the components were subject to various changes:

- Both parts of「艸」migrated to the top,「屯」moved to the middle, and「日」moved to the bottom:

  <kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image]
  蔡侯墓殘鐘
  [集成224](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=224&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
  [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)・[帛](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_Silk_Manuscript)
  [image]
  甲1.2
  新蔡葛陵</kbd>
  <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
  [image]
  [艸部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=46)
  [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>

  > The last form above is the same as the image in the question.
- 「屯」and「艸」switched places:

  <kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
  簡
  [image]
  日乙252
  [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd>
- Everything apart from「日」was graphically corrupted, leading on to the modern form:

  <kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
  篆～[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
  [image]
  乙前85下
  [馬王堆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts)[老子](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching)</kbd><kbd>今
  [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Comment: incredible. recognise the character from such low resolution picture :)

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 do you have any other ideas? the character in the photo seems to be missing a stroke for it to be 萅.

Comment: well, with a structure ⿳; 艸 as the top, 日 as the bottom, not many choices: 著, 萫, 萶, 萻 & 蓍. as usual, without any further evidences, clearer pictures; i support your finding :)